# Mongo Stitch, trigger delete operation doesn't fire

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

stitch app, trigger with insert,update,delete,replace operation types enabled, all apart from "delete" fire up fine but delete doesn't. Steps to reproduce, create or use existing doc in the db, do collection.deleteOne, trigger doesn't fire. 
Any clues would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Pavel

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be really simple.. I have filters (match expressions) to fire triggers for specific docs only so as "delete" change event doesn't have a doc associated with it, it simply didn't get included.